# How to v-bind the button id attribute using Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm sure there is a way to do that, but I can't understand why it doesn't work for me (I'm completely new to vuejs)

I tried using the button tag:

```
<div v-for="line in lines">
    <button v-bind:id="line.id" name="availabilityCheck" type="button">
        Check availability
    </button>
</div>
```

And the button type input:

```
<div v-for="line in lines">
    <input v-bind:id="line.id" name="availabilityCheck" type="button" value="Check availability" />
</div>
```

What happens is that the browser removes the part `v-bind:id="line.id"` so basically the generated buttons do not have an id.

Comment: Are you sure you can use v-bind:id ? You can use v-bind:class, or v-bind:[key]

I just find somenthing else :  v-bind="{ id: someProp, 'other-attr': otherProp }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why it is not working for you but it should ideally work if your lines array contains id property in the objects.

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    lines: [{
        id: 1
    }, {
        id: 2
    }, {
        id: 3
    }, {
        id: 4
    }, {
        id: 5
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="line in lines" :key="line.id">
    <input v-bind:id="line.id" name="availabilityCheck" type="button" value="Check availability" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot **:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<div v-for="line in lines">
    <button :id="'lin'+line.id" name="availabilityCheck" 
        type="button">
        Check availability
    </button>
</div>
```

**Add a constant on prefix may be it work**